# Batch API processes next operation if existing operation is taking too much time

Tags: 7, batch-operations

I am using batch api for processing the operations.
In my operation I am sending xml request to different-different external server and waiting for its response, after getting its response I am processing it.

But sometimes it is taking too much time.
In case where it is taking too much time (If response is taking more than 2 minute). I want to process the next operation.

I checked [batch_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/batch_set/7) but could found the way.
How to implement it?

Comment: This is probably more of a PHP than Drupal question, but could you edit the question to provide the code that's making the external request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this using php.

Here is the sample code

```
$operations[] = array('batch_function_1');
$operations[] = array('batch_function_2');

$batch = array(
  'title' => t('Processing'),
  'operations' => $operations,
  'init_message' => t('Please wait processing is starting.....'),
  'progress_message' => t('Processed @current out of @total.'),
  'error_message' => t('Processing has encountered an error.'),
  'finished' => 'processing_finished',
);

batch_set($batch);
```

In case of soap I achieved using [default_socket_timeout](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php)

```
function batch_function_1 () {
  ini_set("default_socket_timeout", $time);
  try{
    $client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl));
  }
  catch(Exception $e) {
    dpm('Timeout'); // echo 'Timeout';                                                                                                        
  }
}
```

And timeout when using exec.

```
function batch_function_2 () {
  // $command : Which needs to be executed for communicating with server.                                                                       
  exec("timeout {$time} {$command}", $output);
}
```

I also tried the [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) which was not working with batch api.